# How can I create a counter for certain values in a list? for google appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

[Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, Yes, No, Yes, Yes, No, Yes] this list I need to count and assign a variable the amount of Yes's there are in this list and another variable the amount of No's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the number of `Yes` and `No` from the array of `["Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes"]` using Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the for loop is used.

#### Sample script:

```
var ar = ["Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes"];
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
  var e = ar[i];
  if (obj[e]) {
    obj[e] += 1;
  } else {
    obj[e] = 1;
  }
}
Logger.log(obj);  // {"Yes":9,"No":2}
```

#### Test run:

```js
var ar = ["Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes"];
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
  var e = ar[i];
  if (obj[e]) {
    obj[e] += 1;
  } else {
    obj[e] = 1;
  }
}
console.log(obj);  // {"Yes":9,"No":2}
console.log(obj.Yes)
console.log(obj.No)
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the reduce is used.

#### Sample script:

```
const ar = ["Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes"];
const obj = ar.reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e]: (o[e] ? o[e] + 1 : 1)}), {});
console.log(obj);  // {"Yes":9,"No":2}
```

- In this case, the spread syntax can also be used like `{...o, [e]: (o[e] ? o[e] + 1 : 1)}`. But the process cost of the spread syntax is much higher than that of `Object.assign`. So here, I proposed `Object.assign`. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/7198bc9019202f4080de8fd2e1b278fb#6-only-reduce-objectassign-and-spread-syntax)

#### Test run:

```js
const ar = ["Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes"];
const obj = ar.reduce((o, e) => Object.assign(o, {[e]: (o[e] ? o[e] + 1 : 1)}), {});
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.Yes)
console.log(obj.No)
```

### Note:

- In the case of above scripts, The values of `Yes` and `No` can be retrieved with `obj.Yes` and `obj.No`, respectively.
- About pattern 2, please use V8.

### References:

- [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- [Benchmark: Process Costs under V8 using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/7198bc9019202f4080de8fd2e1b278fb)

Comment: @Steven Bui Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.